# why I can not use **kwargs

Tags: python, extends

When I extend a parent class which has a `**kwargs`, I can not write `kwargs` in `super(ParentClass, self).__init__(args, kwargs)`. Why is it like this?

Code as follows:
Originally I think below is right, but it is not.

```
class Parent(object):
  def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    pass

class Child(Parent):
  def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super(Child, self).__init__(args, kwargs)
```

In fact, below it is right after I test.

```
class Parent(object):
  def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    pass

class Child(Parent):
  def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super(Child, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```

When we reference a arg like `*args`, `**kwargs`, usually we directly use `args`, `kwargs`. Why here when I write a `__init__`, I can not do that?

Comment: When *calling* another function, you want to re-apply those variable (keyword) arguments, and use similar syntax. This is called argument unpacking.

Comment: Does it mean we dont unpack in the calling function?

Comment: the examples code not my right code .i change it .

Comment: my question is when we call another function, we use a actual arg to pass. like **kwargs, i think kwargs is the actual arg, why we can't directly pass kwargs here.

Comment: ** means unpacking. got it. thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use

```
class Child(Parent):
  def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super(Child, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```

In order to unpack the kwargs (and args)

And your second issue is that the first argument of the init should be `self` which is the instance.

When you do `super(Child, self).something` you're basically saying we call `something` on the parent instance.

When you do `__init__(*args, **args)` the first argument is the instance (in your case `args[0]`). So `super(Child, self).__init__(*args[1:], **kwargs)` would have worked but it's better (way better) to use `self` and it'll work.

Comment: The OP is (I think) asking *why* that is. Note that they are *already* doing this in their question!

Comment: sorry. i changed it. my question not that self in fact.

Comment: my question is when we call another function, we use a actual arg to pass. like **kwargs, i think kwargs is the actual arg, why we can't directly pass kwargs here.

Comment: then you should probably read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36901/what-does-double-star-and-star-do-for-python-parameters. Basically kwargs is a dictionary, but when **-operator is used it unpacks the key, value into named parameters for a function. if you don't use the `**` then your basically just passing a single parameter which is a dict.